# 8 строчка кода выдаёт ошибку... Объясните, как пофиксить

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая выводит количество элементов квадратной матрицы в каждой строке, больших среднего арифметического элементов данной строки.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаётся натуральное число nn — количество строк и столбцов в матрице, затем элементы матрицы (целые числа) построчно через пробел.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести nn чисел — для каждой строки количество элементов матрицы, больших среднего арифметического элементов данной строки.

```
n = int(input())
q = 0
w = 0
m = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        q += int(m[i][j])
    if q // n <= int(m[i][y for y in range(n)]):
        w += 1
    print(q, w)
    q = 0
    w = 0
```

Я новичок, так что простите, если творю что-то глупое))

Comment: Какую именно ошибку? Текст ошибки предназначен, чтобы его читать, а не игнорировать

Comment: if q // n <= int(m[i][y for y in range(n)]):
Syntax Error: invalid syntax: <string>, line 8, pos 29

Comment: `int(m[i][y for y in range(n)]` Адресация вместо числа сразу списком? Это что-то новенькое...

Comment: Расскажите, что вы хотите сказать этой конструкцией: `int(m[i][y for y in range(n)])`. С точки зрения Python это не имеет смысла. Вообще, пока только учитесь, лучше освоиться с обычными циклами, потом уже переходить к списковым выражениям.

Comment: Может хотели что-то такое? `if all(q // n <= int(m[i][y]) for y in range(n)):`

Comment: @GrAnd -  кстати, интересная идея для будущих создателей ЯП :-). В Python, увы, не реализованная.

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупость, это я так пытаюсь подставить каждое число из списка m[i], что бы сравнить его с другим.. Не придумал, как сделать иначе

Comment: @CheBoore_ka Ну вон я выше написал как надо было. Если хотели чтобы все числа удовлетворяли этому условию. Если нужно, чтобы любое число удовлетворяло, то вместо `all()` используйте `any()`.

Comment: @GrAnd, там по условию нужно посчитать количество элементов в строке, которые больше среднего значения. Если через all - получится проверка, что все элементы больше среднего арифметического, а через any - хотя бы один элемент больше среднего арифметического. А нужно просто вложенный цикл `for j in range(n):` еще раз сделать, в нем проверку.

Comment: @insolor А я задание даже не читал. :) Тогда там выходит просто `w = sum(q // n <= int(m[i][y]) for y in range(n))`. Раз уж человек хотел в одну строчку цикл запихнуть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую сначала освоить обычные циклы, потом уже переходить к list comprehension, а не пытаться их методом тыка использовать.

После того, как посчитали сумму элементов в строке, вам нужно еще раз таким же циклом по этой же строке пройти и посчитать количество элементов больше среднего:

```
n = int(input())
m = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    q = 0
    for j in range(n):
        q += int(m[i][j])

    average = q / n
    w = 0
    for j in range(n):
        if int(m[i][j]) > average:
            w += 1

    print(q, w)
```

То же самое в более "питоничном" стиле (без использования индексов):

```
n = int(input())
m = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
for row in m:
    q = 0
    for item in row:
        q += int(item)

    average = q / n
    w = 0
    for item in row:
        if int(item) > average:
            w += 1

    print(q, w)
```